# Next Auth with Firebase Adapter how to sign in with email and password

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, firebase-authentication, next-auth

i using `next-auth` for authentication with Firebase adapter, but I'm not sure how i should sign in the users. I do not want to sign in with my google account, I have users accounts in a firebase project and i just want to sign them in with email and password.

This is my `route.ts` file in `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

```
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    credential: cert({
      projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY!.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
    }),
  }) as Adapter,
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      const userEmail = credentials!["email"] as string;
      const psw = credentials!["password"] as string;
      console.log(credentials);
      return false;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
};

export const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I was trying to sign in like this

```
  const onSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      await signIn("credentials", { email: "myeemail", password: "123123" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

But nothing was printed, so I'm not even sure if the `signIn` callback was being called.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, I think you will need to make a few modifications to your code.

Here is my solution list:

Remove the GoogleProvider from the providers array in your authOptions. This will ensure that only email and password authentication is used.

Modify the signIn callback function in your authOptions to handle the email and password sign-in process. Here’s an example implementation:

```
    callbacks: {
      async signIn({ email, password }) {
        try {
          // Implement your custom sign-in logic here
          // e.g., verify the email and password against your Firebase project
          const user = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    
          if (user) {
            // Return the user object if sign-in is successful
            return user;
          } else {
            // Return false if sign-in fails
            return false;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          // Handle any errors that occur during sign-in
          console.error(error);
          return false;
        }
      },
    },
```

Update your onSignIn function to pass the email and password to the signIn method. Make sure to replace “myemail” and “123123” with the actual email and password you want to use for sign-in.

With these modifications, when you call the onSignIn function, it will trigger the signIn callback in your authOptions, which will attempt to sign in the user with the provided email and password using Firebase. You should see the result of the sign-in attempt in the console.

```
    const onSignIn = async () => {
      try {
        await signIn("credentials", { email: "myemail", password: "123123" });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
```

Make sure you have properly set up your Firebase project and configured the environment variables for your Next.js application.

I am very happy to see you again! If you are busy, I can help you via remote work.

I hope you are doing well!